# Arrays object property is not updating

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, object

this is my first post here. Please excuse my poor code, I will try my best to describe my issue.

I'm building a Library app from Odin Project. Currently I'm able to create an object with values I'm inputting in a popup form. Created object is being displayed on the screen with correct values as intended.

My goal is to update Read status in a myLibrary array when I click on a button. I was able to update the text content on the button with a click, unfortunately I have no idea how to update a read value in an array for the created object.

I would really appreciate any suggestions.
Thank you for your time

```js
let myLibrary = [];

const registerBook = document.getElementById("registerBook");
const title = document.getElementById("title");
const author = document.getElementById("author");
const pages = document.getElementById("pages");
let read = document.getElementById("read-btn");
let form = document.getElementById("bookForm");
let optionYes = document.getElementById("option-yes");
let optionNo = document.getElementById("option-no");

function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("bookForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("bookForm").style.display = "none";
}

registerBook.addEventListener("click", function() {

  myLibrary.push({
    title: title.value,
    author: author.value,
    pages: pages.value,
    read: read.value,
  })
  renderBooks();
  console.log(myLibrary);

})

function renderBooks() {

  let bookShelf = document.querySelector('#bookShelf');

  let bookCover = document.createElement('div');
  bookCover.classList.add('bookCover');
  bookShelf.appendChild(bookCover);

  let deleteCard = document.createElement('div');
  deleteCard.classList.add('delete-card');
  deleteCard.id = "deleteCard";
  bookCover.append(deleteCard);

  let bookTitleTag = document.createElement('div');
  bookTitleTag.classList.add('book-title-tag');
  bookCover.append(bookTitleTag);
  bookTitleTag.textContent = 'Book title:';

  let bookTitle = document.createElement('div');
  bookTitle.classList.add('book-title');
  bookCover.append(bookTitle);

  let bookAuthorTag = document.createElement('div');
  bookAuthorTag.classList.add('book-author-tag');
  bookCover.append(bookAuthorTag);
  bookAuthorTag.textContent = 'Book author:';

  let bookAuthor = document.createElement('div');
  bookAuthor.classList.add('book-author');
  bookCover.append(bookAuthor);

  let bookPagesTag = document.createElement('div');
  bookPagesTag.classList.add('book-pages-tag');
  bookCover.append(bookPagesTag);
  bookPagesTag.textContent = 'No of pages:';

  let bookPages = document.createElement('div');
  bookPages.classList.add('book-pages');
  bookCover.append(bookPages);

  let bookStatusTag = document.createElement('div');
  bookStatusTag.classList.add('book-pages-tag');
  bookCover.append(bookStatusTag);
  bookStatusTag.textContent = 'Have you read the book?:';

  let bookStatus = document.createElement('button');
  bookStatus.classList.add('book-status-btn');
  bookStatus.id = 'book-status-btn';
  bookCover.append(bookStatus);

  bookTitle.textContent = title.value;
  bookAuthor.textContent = author.value;
  bookPages.textContent = pages.value;
  bookStatus.textContent = read.value;

  /*Book status in card is updated */
  bookStatus.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (bookStatus.textContent === 'Yes') {
      bookStatus.textContent = 'No'
    } else {
      if (bookStatus.textContent === 'No') {
        bookStatus.textContent = 'Yes'
      }
    }
  });

  /* Trying to update array */
  bookStatus.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (bookCover.read === 'Yes') {
      bookCover.read = 'No'
    } else {
      if (bookCover.read === 'No') {
        bookCover.read = 'Yes'
      }
    }
    console.log(myLibrary);
  });


  deleteCard.addEventListener("click", () => {
    bookShelf.removeChild(bookCover);
    myLibrary.splice(bookCover, 1);
  });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script defer src="index.js"></script>
  <title>Library</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">Library</div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="add-book-btn" id="addBookBtn" onclick="openForm()">Add Book</div>
        <!--<div class="login-btn">Log in</div> -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">

      <div class="form-popup" id="bookForm">
        <form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="event.preventDefault()" class="form-container">

          <div class="form-popup-close" onclick="closeForm()"></div>
          <h1>Add Book</h1>

          <label for="title"><b>Book title</b></label>
          <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Enter book title" name="title" required>

          <label for="author"><b>Author</b></label>
          <input type="text" id="author" placeholder="Enter author name" name="author">

          <label for="pages"><b>No. of pages</b></label>
          <input type="number" id="pages" placeholder="Number of pages" name="pages">

          <div class="form-bot">
            <p>Have you read it?</p>

            <select name="read" id="read-btn">
              <option id="option-yes" value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option id="option-no" value="No">No</option>
            </select>

          </div>

          <button type="button" class="btn" id="registerBook" onclick="closeForm()">Register Book</button>


        </form>

      </div>

      <div id="bookShelf"></div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the title from the `bbookTitle` DIV, and search the array for that title.  Then you can toggle the `read` property.

```js
let myLibrary = [];

const registerBook = document.getElementById("registerBook");
const title = document.getElementById("title");
const author = document.getElementById("author");
const pages = document.getElementById("pages");
let read = document.getElementById("read-btn");
let form = document.getElementById("bookForm");
let optionYes = document.getElementById("option-yes");
let optionNo = document.getElementById("option-no");

function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("bookForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("bookForm").style.display = "none";
}

registerBook.addEventListener("click", function() {

  myLibrary.push({
    title: title.value,
    author: author.value,
    pages: pages.value,
    read: read.value,
  })
  renderBooks();
  console.log(myLibrary);

})

function renderBooks() {

  let bookShelf = document.querySelector('#bookShelf');

  let bookCover = document.createElement('div');
  bookCover.classList.add('bookCover');
  bookShelf.appendChild(bookCover);

  let deleteCard = document.createElement('div');
  deleteCard.classList.add('delete-card');
  deleteCard.id = "deleteCard";
  bookCover.append(deleteCard);

  let bookTitleTag = document.createElement('div');
  bookTitleTag.classList.add('book-title-tag');
  bookCover.append(bookTitleTag);
  bookTitleTag.textContent = 'Book title:';

  let bookTitle = document.createElement('div');
  bookTitle.classList.add('book-title');
  bookCover.append(bookTitle);

  let bookAuthorTag = document.createElement('div');
  bookAuthorTag.classList.add('book-author-tag');
  bookCover.append(bookAuthorTag);
  bookAuthorTag.textContent = 'Book author:';

  let bookAuthor = document.createElement('div');
  bookAuthor.classList.add('book-author');
  bookCover.append(bookAuthor);

  let bookPagesTag = document.createElement('div');
  bookPagesTag.classList.add('book-pages-tag');
  bookCover.append(bookPagesTag);
  bookPagesTag.textContent = 'No of pages:';

  let bookPages = document.createElement('div');
  bookPages.classList.add('book-pages');
  bookCover.append(bookPages);

  let bookStatusTag = document.createElement('div');
  bookStatusTag.classList.add('book-pages-tag');
  bookCover.append(bookStatusTag);
  bookStatusTag.textContent = 'Have you read the book?:';

  let bookStatus = document.createElement('button');
  bookStatus.classList.add('book-status-btn');
  bookStatus.id = 'book-status-btn';
  bookCover.append(bookStatus);

  bookTitle.textContent = title.value;
  bookAuthor.textContent = author.value;
  bookPages.textContent = pages.value;
  bookStatus.textContent = read.value;

  /*Book status in card is updated */
  bookStatus.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (bookStatus.textContent === 'Yes') {
      bookStatus.textContent = 'No'
    } else {
      if (bookStatus.textContent === 'No') {
        bookStatus.textContent = 'Yes'
      }
    }
  });

  /* Trying to update array */
  bookStatus.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let title = bookTitle.textContent;
    let book = myLibrary.find(book => book.title === title);
    if (book) {
      book.read = book.read === 'Yes' ? 'No' : 'Yes';
      bookStatus.textContent = book.read;
    }
    console.log(myLibrary);
  });


  deleteCard.addEventListener("click", () => {
    bookShelf.removeChild(bookCover);
    myLibrary.splice(bookCover, 1);
  });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script defer src="index.js"></script>
  <title>Library</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">Library</div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="add-book-btn" id="addBookBtn" onclick="openForm()">Add Book</div>
        <!--<div class="login-btn">Log in</div> -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">

      <div class="form-popup" id="bookForm">
        <form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="event.preventDefault()" class="form-container">

          <div class="form-popup-close" onclick="closeForm()"></div>
          <h1>Add Book</h1>

          <label for="title"><b>Book title</b></label>
          <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Enter book title" name="title" required>

          <label for="author"><b>Author</b></label>
          <input type="text" id="author" placeholder="Enter author name" name="author">

          <label for="pages"><b>No. of pages</b></label>
          <input type="number" id="pages" placeholder="Number of pages" name="pages">

          <div class="form-bot">
            <p>Have you read it?</p>

            <select name="read" id="read-btn">
              <option id="option-yes" value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option id="option-no" value="No">No</option>
            </select>

          </div>

          <button type="button" class="btn" id="registerBook" onclick="closeForm()">Register Book</button>


        </form>

      </div>

      <div id="bookShelf"></div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```